# Append values from one column within a row that is based on a filter in another column

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am working on one excel-file and openpyxl. There are two worksheets in this file. Sheet 1 with several columns and Sheet 2 has several columns too which one of them is equal to one in sheet 1.

The steps I want to do with Openpyxl are as follows. At first, I want to filter the first column of sheet 1 based on some string "New" so that only a subset of rows is considered. Afterwards, I would like to take values (ID) that are on the same row as the filtered results but in a different column and append these cells to sheet 2 to the first column.

I somehow cannot figure out the coordinates of the rows/col for this to success.

Right now I have found from somewhere else:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("workbook.xlsx")
sheet1 = wb["sheet_1"]
sheet2 = wb["sheet_2"]

for row in sheet1.iter_rows():
    if row[0].value == "New":
        sheet2.append(cell.value for cell in row)
```

[image: sheet_1]
[image: sheet2 with appended IDs from sheet1]

Comment: Excel Filtering is only a visual change. Filtering the first sheet on "new" will show only those rows where column A contains "new", however the intermediatary rows (in this case 2 & 3) are just hidden. Iterating the rows with Openpyxl will still process these two rows. Therefore the usefulness of filtering first seems limited. Perhaps you should ignore the first requirement and continue with the second using your code.

Comment: If you want to copy just the value in the 'ID' column (B) only and append to the 2nd sheet you can use cell offset to get the value one cell across, like **sheet2.append([row[0].offset(column=1).value])**